# What .NET framework version do you have installed on production servers?

Tags: .net

Just out of curiosity - what version of the .NET framework does your company have installed on its production Windows web and SQL Servers ?

How big a struggle will it be to get a new .NET version on those servers, e.g. .NET 4.0 when it comes out end of 2009 ??

As a software developer, I find myself often struggling with IT departments trying to convince them to install .NET, but a lot of departments and sysadmins seem to be awfully hesitant....

Marc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have whatever version is required for the application software installed on the server computer. If the server computer doesn't have any applications installed that require a .NET Framework installed, we don't install one. I have no problem installing it, but like any software on a server computer, if it's not required it's not installed.

Comment: I wish I had you as my sysadmin here! :-)

Comment: Many people wish they did... *smile*

Answer (score 2):

Windows 2008 automatically installs .NET Framework by default, taking the decision out of it. And since every version of the Framework can sit side-by-side with older versions, its safe to install multiple versions on a server.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the hesitation is due to security concerns and admins wanting to "wait for SP1 to come".

That said, we install what is necessary to make things work so long as the framework is in public release.  No beta or RC versions on production servers.  And if a version isn't required (or the whole Framework for that matter) it doesn't make it on.